# Refreshing a package project in Eclipse PyDev

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I have a PyDev project that is organized like this (I have omitted the `.git` directory). The aim is to build a package called `stattests`.

```
    |   .gitignore
    |   .project
    |   .pydevproject
    |   
    +---.git
    +---stattests
    |   |   setup.py
    |   |   
    |   +---tests
    |   |   |   tests.py
    |   |   |   __init__.py
    |           
    \---unittests
            tests1.py
```

The top level directory `stattests` contains the `setup.py` file, and the sub-folder `tests`, a module that contains an `__init__.py` which imports all the functions from `tests.py` in the same module folder. Note that tests here are not unit tests, but statistical tests.

Unit tests are contained in the `unittests` folder, and the  which looks like this:

```
# unittests/tests1.py
from stattests.tests import tests
series1 = pd.Series(np.random.randn(10))
tests.test1(series1)
```

When I execute this testing script it does not refresh the definition of the `stattests.tests.test1` function, and uses an old definition instead.

I have also manually added all the folder and subfolders of the project to the project `PYTHONPATH` property.

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have: 'User Module Deleter (UMD)' (preferences > pydev > interactive console > user module deleter) > enable UMD activated?

I.e.: If you are only sending it to the console modules are cached in sys.module, so, imported modules aren't usually re-evaluated... now, UMD, if enabled, tries to force those to reload by using 'runfile' instead of 'execfile) -- although this can be sometimes tricky, so, it may fail too -- so, if you want to do a simple run, the recommended way is running with F9 (run current module), and Ctrl+Alt+Enter is recommended if you want to use the symbols defined afterwards interactively in the shell.

Comment: Thanks. Will check and report back.

Answer (score 0):

If it isn't updating then you can clear the cache and make sure you edited and saved the right file. In the project structure there should be a folder called **pycache** just delete it. Another way to refresh in eclipse is to right click > refresh on the project in the PyDevPackage Explorer or press F5.

Comment: Tried both before posting. Running the test script as a Python script does work, but either refreshing, or deleting pycache does not. By the way, my preferred mode of execution is `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`Enter` to send to a console.

Comment: it sounds like you might have duplicate files or something is automatically happening in the console. Other things to try would be to restart eclipse or try to run the program through a regular terminal with __python tests1.py__